# Use MATLAB's webread to login to website and extract text

Tags: matlab, text, web, passwords

I'm wondering how to extract text from a password protected website using Matlab's "webread" function. I have the following code (part of which i got from [here](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/973-how-do-i-read-text-from-html-file)):

```
values=inputdlg({'Url','Username:','Password'});
options=weboptions('Username',values{2},'Password',values{3},'Timeout',Inf);
html=webread(values{1},options);
txt = regexprep(html,'<script.*?/script>','');
txt = regexprep(txt,'<style.*?/style>','');
txt = regexprep(txt,'<.*?>','');
```

But it gets stuck at the login window for every webpage I've tried. Help? Ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The [weboptions](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/weboptions.html) username and password parameters are for [basic HTTP authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication), which is different than logging into Stack Exchange, Gmail, etc though the username and password boxes on a web page.

Some sites provide other mechanisms that might allow you to log in (like OAuth), and the File Exchange has a smattering of clients.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an OAuth interface for login into the flicker using Matlab, maybe it help you. but you have to be sure that your website support this authentification method (as "Matt Krause" mentioned in his answer).

[Link to Tutorial](https://de.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/34162-flickr-api-with-oauth-based-user-authentication?focused=5204781&tab=example)

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.